# Omitting an instance field at run time in Java

Tags: java, jvm, metaprogramming, jvm-hotspot

Java's assert mechanism allows disabling putting in assertions which have essentially no run time cost (aside from a bigger class file) if assertions are disabled.  But this may cover all situations.

For instance, many of Java's collections feature "fail-fast" iterators that attempt to detect when you're using them in a thread-unsafe way.  But this requires both the collection and the iterator itself to maintain extra state that would not be needed if these checks weren't there.

Suppose someone wanted to do something similar, but allow the checks to be disabled and if they are disabled, it saves a few bytes in the iterator and likewise a few more bytes in the ArrayList, or whatever.

Alternatively, suppose we're doing some sort of object pooling that we want to be able to turn on and off at runtime; when it's off, it should just use Java's garbage collection and take no room for reference counts, like this (note that the code as written is very broken):

```
class MyClass {
    static final boolean useRefCounts = my.global.Utils.useRefCounts();
    static {
        if(useRefCounts)
            int refCount; // want instance field, not local variable
    }
    void incrementRefCount(){
        if(useRefCounts) refCount++; // only use field if it exists;
    }
    /**return true if ready to be collected and reused*/
    boolean decrementAndTestRefCount(){
        // rely on Java's garbage collector if ref counting is disabled.
        return useRefCounts && --refCount == 0;
    }
}
```

The trouble with the above code is that the static bock makes no sense.  But is there some trick using low-powered magic to make something along these lines work?  (If high powered magic is allowed, the nuclear option is generate two versions of MyClass and arrange to put the correct one on the class path at start time.)

Comment: I don't think there's any trick to this.  You have to write code to deal with your use case, if you actually have one.  Java class definitions are fixed at compile time, unless you get into byte code manipulation at runtime, which is possible to do, but very difficult.  Best left for experts.

Comment: Even with run-time bytecode manipulation, is this possible?  My goal is not to change the definition of any methods, but to conditionally include or exclude an instance field from a class.  My knowledge of this level of deep sorcery is very weak, but I've never heard of it being done.

Comment: I think with byte code manipulation anything is possible.  You can implement totally different languages in a JVM.  But it's going to be a lot of work.  Good luck.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Code_Engineering_Library

Comment: You are overestimating the impact of a single field. Depending on the JVM settings, there is an object alignment and hence, padding, of at least eight bytes, so it’s possible that the extra field has no impact at all. Further, objects like iterators are usually decomposed into variables after Escape Analysis has proven their pure local nature. But even if not, how does the storage of a single field matter for a temporary object that is abandoned shortly after its creation?

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the link to BCEL.  I need to look at that at some point.  Looks fancy, but way too tricky.

Comment: Yes, iterators are short-lived, but my use case applies to fairly long-lived objects.  It adds up.  It's not, like, half the memory, or even 10%, but it does add up.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: You might not need to do this at all. The JIT is very good at inlining constants known at runtime especially `boolean` and optimising away the code which isn't used.

The `int` field is not ideal, however, if you are using a 64 bit JVM, the object size might not change.

On the OpenJDK/Oracle JVM (64-bit), the header is 12 bytes by default. The object alignment is 8 byte so the object will use 16 bytes.  The field, adds 4 bytes, which after alignment is also 16 bytes.

---

To answer the question, you need two classes (unless you use generated code or hacks)

```
class MyClass {
    static final boolean useRefCounts = my.global.Utils.useRefCounts();

    public static MyClass create() {
        return useRefCounts ? new MyClassPlus() : new MyClass();
    }

    void incrementRefCount() {
    }

    boolean decrementAndTestRefCount() {
        return false;
    }
}

class MyClassPlus extends MyClass {
    int refCount; // want instance field, not local variable

    void incrementRefCount() {
        refCount++; // only use field if it exists;
    }

    boolean decrementAndTestRefCount() {
        return --refCount == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the JIT possible know whether the field will be used by reflection or not?  It has to keep it.

Comment: @MarkVY in principle, a JVM can de-optimize code when an actual Reflection access happens, though, I doubt that the current version of HotSpot does this. But as said [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487415/omitting-an-instance-field-at-run-time-in-java#comment91926455_52487415) and also in this answer, it is possible that the presence or absence of the field has no impact at all, as you are only toggling between a field and an unused space, due to object alignment. If you are still worrying about a single field, this answer has show a practical solution.

Comment: True, there is a 50% chance that this makes no difference, depending on alignment, but also a 50% it makes 8 bytes of difference.  So on average, it still makes 4 bytes of difference.  And average is the right thing to do here, because there are hundreds of such classes in the code base.  For similar reasons, this answer is not very convenient, since when there are hundreds of classes, it comes down to "write everything twice".  You'd need compile time code generation to make this even slightly palatable.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a slightly higher overhead in the case you’re using your ref count, you may resort to external storage, i.e.

```
class MyClass {
    static final WeakHashMap<MyClass,Integer> REF_COUNTS
        = my.global.Utils.useRefCounts()? new WeakHashMap<>(): null;

    void incrementRefCount() {
        if(REF_COUNTS != null) REF_COUNTS.merge(this, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    /**return true if ready to be collected and reused*/
    boolean decrementAndTestRefCount() {
        return REF_COUNTS != null
            && REF_COUNTS.compute(this, (me, i) -> --i == 0? null: i) == null;
    }
}
```

There is a behavioral difference for the case that someone invokes `decrementAndTestRefCount()` more often than `incrementRefCount()`. While your original code silently runs into a negative ref count, this code will throw a `NullPointerException`. I prefer failing with an exception in this case…

The code above will leave you with the overhead of a single `static` field in case you’re not using the feature. Most JVMs should have no problems eliminating the conditionals regarding the state of a `static final` variable.

Note further that the code allows `MyClass` instances to get garbage collected while having a non-zero ref count, just like when it was an instance field, but also actively removes the mapping when the count reaches the initial state of zero again, to minimize the work needed for cleanup.

Comment: Clever solution actually; never thought to use external storage.  Unfortunately, overhead is actually quite a bit higher once you take into account annoyances like thread safety.  Anyway, was more curious about the general idea of conditionally excluding fields.  But wow,  external.  Nice.